# How to retain permissions for a user in Lookup field?

Tags: 2010, permissions, lookup-column

I have column level permission using a custom code. But I am unable to retain permissions for a user in Lookup field! Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How are you managing the permission in your custom field? Can you give some code?

Comment: Its a third party code purchased from a company. Since it is beyond the scope of this forum I am unable to share as I don't want to look like I am asking for a solution to a third party product. I am just asking whether SharePoint has any inbuilt tweak to retain permission in lookup fields

Comment: then chase down the third party, report it as a bug

Comment: Haha sneaky sneaky so you're trying to get around the "no third party" rule? :P I'm assuming since this is custom code then it depends on how their code is written. Anyways... I don't understand the "retain permission in lookup field" thing. Is it a lookup column to a list of normal choices? Does the user have access to only a few items in the lookup list?

Comment: I need to save original permissions of a user in Lookup fields also.